# Angular data not showing in template

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have Ionic app with angular and I get my data on `constructor` but can't print them in `html`

## Code

`component`

```
receiver: any;

constructor(
    //....
) {
    // get receiver data
    const receiverData = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('receiverData');
    console.log('receiver data: ', receiverData); // does print the data (sample data below)
    this.receiver = receiverData;
}
```

`HTML`

```
<ion-title [innerHTML]="receiver?.username"></ion-title>
```

`Sample data (returned by "console.log('receiver data: ', receiverData);"`

```
receiver data:  {
  "id":4,
  "name":"Tester",
  "username":"Utester",
  "phone":"081000000000",
  "photo":null,
  "email":"tester@admin.com",
  "created_at":"2020-06-21T09:06:15.000000Z"
}
```

**Any idea why my data not printing in html?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally if it is object it works fine without problem. But you may send string as type then try to parse it

```
 this.receiver = JSON.parse(receiverData);
```